# Como dar Refresh na Página sem perder o que está no $_POST['x']?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Olá
Estou usando este método para atualizar a pagina:

header("Refresh: 0");

mas não gostaria de perder o que está no $_POST...

Como proceder nessa situação?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php ou http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php

Comment: Salva em algum lugar. Banco de dados, cookies, localStorage

Comment: Acho que a forma mais simple e fazer um `$_SESSION["post"] = $_POST;`